# restapi with Nginx and uwsgi not passing headers info

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I have a flask app that runs fine with just uwsgi as a service on port 5000.  I am trying to use Nginx to proxy https to port 5000 in the back end.  It is hitting my app, but my app requires auth tokens to be sent on the header and I am not getting it when proxying through Nginx.  However if I change the URL to port 5000 the headers are passed.  How can I configure Nginx to pass everything to the app?  This app does GET,PUSH,PUT,DELETE and users will be sending not only the header, but json data as well.

```
##################### NGINX CONFIG #####################
    location /customer/ {
            include uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass unix:///var/www/html/cisco/cisco.sock;
    }
    

##################### UWSGI CONFIG #####################        
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:application

master = true
processes = 5

uid=apache
gid=apache

buffer-size = 32768

http = 0.0.0.0:5000

req-logger = file:/var/log/uwsgi/cart-req.log
logger = file:/var/log/uwsgi/cart-err.log

chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = true
socket = cisco.sock

die-on-term = false

py-autoreload = 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asume we are talking about request headers. In this case you can use this directive `uwsgi_pass_request_headers      on;` in your location-block:

```
  location /customer/ {
            include uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass_request_headers on;
            uwsgi_pass unix:///var/www/html/cisco/cisco.sock;
    }
```

However `on` is the default value so if not turned off anywere else the headers as well as the request-body should be sent to your Python application.

What are your header names? Are you able to update your questions with the header names or even better a example HTTP request in `curl` format?

Comment: This is the curl command that I am using.  The api_key header does not pass through to port 5000.
`curl --location --request GET 'http://some.domain.com:5000/customer/' \
--header 'api_key: someKey'`

Comment: If your Flask-Application IS NOT receiving the header on port `5000` NGINX is not the problem as the reuquest will not go through nginx at all.  In your questions you are saying on port `5000` everything works fine. Can you please check if the headers are present if the requet goes strait to port `5000`. Whats the python code?

Comment: Port 5000 is fully functional.  The curl command above is the working code.  That works correctly.  What doesn't work is proxying port 80 through Nginx to port 5000.  The headers dont flow through.  I get the GET request, but not the headers.